# Sum of columns grouped by its row value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to create query to summarize Table1 as follows:

```
Table1:
+-----+------+-----+------+
|Col1 | Col2 |Col3 | Col4 |
|1    | 2    |3    |  1   |
|3    | 2    |1    |  1   |
|2    | 1    |3    |  1   |
+-----+------+-----+------+
Output:   
 +----+---+-----+-----+----+----+                    
 |    | 1 |  2  |  3  |  4 |  5 |    
 +----+---+-----+-----+----+----+
 |Col1| 1 |  2  |  3  |    |    |      
 |Col2| 1 |  4  |     |    |    |       
 |Col3| 1 |     |  6  |    |    |     
 |Col4| 3 |     |     |    |    |
 +----+---+-----+-----+----+----+
```

My best approach was using TRANSFORM PIVOT.

Comment: please post your best attempt at the SQL.

Comment: @Randy, Thanks for the reply. I posted my best attempt. My plan is to make TRANSFORM PIVOT out of this query since I cannot make it in one query.

Comment: Edit your question to include your best effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to UNPIVOT the data using a `UNION ALL` first, then apply a PIVOT/TRANSFORM:

```
transform sum(val)
select col
from
(
  SELECT 'Col1' as col, Col1 as Val
  FROM test
  union all
  SELECT 'Col2' as col, Col2 as Val
  FROM test
  union all
  SELECT 'Col3' as col, Col3 as Val
  FROM test
  union all
  SELECT 'Col4' as col, Col4 as Val
  FROM test
) src
group by col
pivot val;
```

The UNION ALL query converts the multiple columns `col1`, `col2`, etc into multiple rows in a single columns, then you can apply the TRANSFORM function.

Note: this query was tested in MS Access 2010 and it returned the result:

```
+------+---+---+---+
| col  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+------+---+---+---+
| Col1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Col2 | 1 | 4 |   |
| Col3 | 1 |   | 6 |
| Col4 | 3 |   |   |
+------+---+---+---+
```

Edit, based on your comment that you need all of the values to appear `1-5`, then I would suggest using these minor changes.

First, create a table containing all of the numbers that you want to appear:

```
create table numbers
(
  n number
);

insert into numbers values (1);
insert into numbers values (2);
insert into numbers values (3);
insert into numbers values (4);
insert into numbers values (5);
```

Once you have a table with all of the values that you want to show, then create a separate query with the UNION ALL query from above.  The query below I created and saved it with the name `unpiv` but you can call it whatever:

```
SELECT 'Col1' as col, Col1 as Val 
FROM test
union all
SELECT 'Col2' as col, Col2 as Val
FROM test
union all
SELECT 'Col3' as col, Col3 as Val
FROM test
UNION ALL SELECT 'Col4' as col, Col4 as Val
FROM test;
```

The key to getting the result is to create a list of all of the numbers with each one of the columns so you will use something like this:

```
SELECT col, val
from numbers, (select distinct col from unpiv);
```

This generates a cartesian result of each column name with the number that you want displayed. Finally you take the above query and join it to you `unpiv` query so you can TRANSFORM the data. The final query is:

```
transform sum(u.val)
select src.col
from
(
  SELECT col, val
  from numbers, (select distinct col from unpiv)
) src
left join unpiv u
  on src.col = u.col
  and src.val = u.val
group by src.col
pivot src.val;
```

Tested in MS Access 2010 gives the result:

```
+------+---+---+---+---+---+
| col  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
+------+---+---+---+---+---+
| Col1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |   |   |
| Col2 | 1 | 4 |   |   |   |
| Col3 | 1 |   | 6 |   |   |
| Col4 | 3 |   |   |   |   |
+------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks bluefeet. You answered it correctly but I also need to show columns 4 and 5 regardless if they have values or no values at all.